# Firefox webextension window.resizeTo does not resize for page created by browser.windows.create

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm creating a Firefox webextension with a popup that needs to be resized programmatically depending on the content after the page is rendered.

I have the following code using [browser.windows.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/create) to create a popup window:

```
browser.windows.create({
    type    : 'popup',
    url     : `page.html`,
});
```

Inside `page.html`, after it's rendered, I am trying to resize using:

```
window.resizeTo(<width>,<height>);
```

However this does not do anything. From [window.resizeTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo) doc, it footnote says that:

> Note: It's not possible to resize a window or tab that wasn’t created
> by window.open(). It's also not possible to resize when the window has
> multiple tabs.

I'm guessing this is due to the first reason, since the window was not created using `window.open()`, it is not resizable. Is there an alternative?
I'm trying to avoid using [browser.windows.update](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/update), it adds complexity since I have to send a message with the dimensions. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or any suggestions how to handle this?

Comment: @wOxxOm , thank you! didn't realize you can do that.
Do you wan to put it as an answer so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page.html` is an extension page (just like browser_action popup or an options page) so it has access to `browser` and **you can call `browser.windows.update` directly** just like you call `window.resizeTo` now, no need for messaging.

```js
browser.windows.update(browser.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT, {
  width: 500,
  height: 500,
});
```